# Forcing WebGL texture reload from buffer

Tags: javascript, webgl, electron

I am using (a slightly modified version of) [mmap](https://github.com/geocar/mmap) in [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) to share memory between two different processes. Then I use this memory, in the form of a [buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) to upload a WebGL texture and I use it to draw stuff:

```
buffer = mmap(196608,mmap.PROT_READ,mmap.MAP_SHARED,"shared_mmap",0)

f = function(){
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, 256, 256, 0, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null)
}
```

This works perfectly, the first time. Although I can see the data being changed by the other process (if I evaluate `buffer[100]`in the console) the texture remains the same in the WebGL scene.

However, if I copy the buffer to a TypedArray, it works perfectly:

```
arr = new Uint8Array(buffer)
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, 256, 256, 0, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, arr);
```

The problem is that doing it this way I am repeatedly copying all the data every frame, which kind of defeats the purpose of using a mmap.

Is there a way of updating the WebGL texture with buffer data without copying its contents to a new array every time?

Comment: I didn't know you could pass a node::Buffer to gl.texImage2D. But if it's work the first time, why do you need to copy it to Uint8Array for the update?

Comment: I works the first time, but it does not update with new information in the buffer. The information stored in the buffer changes because it is basically shared memory, but somehow texImage2D doesn't realize that.

Comment: Have you find a solution? I'm in a similar situation with a node native module that renders to a node::Buffer a YUV surface than then is displayed through a webgl canvas... The only way I can make it work is to create a different node::Buffer for every frame (pointing to the same data).

Answer (score -1):

You are not copying the data, with `new Uint8Array(buffer)`, you are creating a new reference to the same data.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) you can read more about DataViews.

Comment: But [in node documentation it says otherwise](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarray):`The Buffer object's memory is copied to the TypedArray, not shared`